# PIR sensor repeatedly giving 1's for a few seconds then 0's

Tags: gpio

I've checked my wiring and my code, then double checked it. The sensor continually outputs 1's for a few seconds then 0's regardless of the actual input. If I give it no inferred light at all is will continue this trend.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    i = GPIO.input(11)
    if i == 0: 
        print "NO intruders", i
        GPIO.output(3, 0)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    elif i == 1:
        print "Intruder detected", i
        GPIO.output(3, 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

[image: pic1]
[image]

Comment: The code looks pretty straightforward. It's going to be difficult to diagnose the problem without a spec sheet or link for your PIR sensor, and a photograph of your wiring. Can you add those to the question?

Comment: Everything looks fine.  Are you sure the power and ground aren't swapped on your infrared sensor?  Mine are in the opposite pins.

Answer (score 1):

Only resistor I see is for the led. 
I dont see an external pull up/down resistor for the input or the internal ones enabled. 
Maybe its a case of noise/floating input showing up as 1s and 0s ? 
Couldn't be sure without the PIR sensor datasheet. 
If the PIR sensor you are using is same/similar to this [one](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-12-sensing-movement/hardware) you should try enabling the internal pull up (or down) like so

`GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)`

and checking if that fixes the problem

Comment: My (similar) infrared sensor does not need pulls.  It defaults to high but goes low for a few seconds when infrared is detected.